# Are players allowed to convert a penalty kick into a "multiple passes goal"?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

Is it legal in football that a player scores a goal in penalty by creating a pass (in forward direction as per rules) to another teammate and get passed back and repeat the passes until they want to score the goal? (any defensive moves from the opposite team are neglected)

Comment: While they are very similar, this question has produced a better answer. It is succinct, there is a link to a web page rather than a bulky PDF, it references the most recent edition of the Laws, and the relevant text is quoted in the body of the answer.

Comment: Similar? They're identical questions. A better answer here, yes, but there's nothing to stop it being placed there, instead of adding separate history here.

Comment: They're certainly not identical. This one asks about multiple passes, while the others ask about single passes. This is irrelevant anyway, as a question isn't required to be identical to be marked as a duplicate. I think it would have been better to have the other question link to this one, as the answer here is up-to-date, but that's a moot point now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. There are essentially only [two major restrictions on play after a penalty kick](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-penalty-kick/chapters/penalty-kick-procedure):

> The player taking the penalty kick must kick the ball forward
>
> [...]
>
> The kicker must not play the ball again until it has touched another player.

So long as those restrictions are met, the ball is in play as in normal play and anything goes.

Comment: Your answer popped up just as I was about to post something nowhere near as succinct. This answer is clear and straight to the point.

Comment: Most famously, Cruyff to Olsen to Cruyff and goal, at YouTube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjGbB0_fUXA

Comment: Probably one of the most famous "trick" penalties of all time.

Comment: I would add that a penalty kick is really a free kick..

Comment: Is this also true in a penalty shootout?

Comment: @thodic No, but that's almost a different question.

Comment: @gbianchi A penalty kick is not a free kick. They are described in separate laws and the procedures are vastly different.

Comment: It's a free kick at the penalty spot.. i will get to you back with the ruling @studro

Comment: It's not a free kick. Free kicks can be taken quickly, played in any direction, the player taking it does not need to be identified, and only opponents need to be ten yards away. None of these points are true for penalty kicks. Free kicks are defined in [Law 13](http://theifab.com/laws/free-kicks/chapters/types-of-free-kick) and penalty kicks are defined in [Law 14](http://theifab.com/laws/the-penalty-kick/chapters/the-penalty-kick-introduction).

Comment: you are rigth @studro, there is a little difference in the spanish translation of the law.. (wording problem, same outcome)...